# Problem at subsetting with one condition R

Tags: r, subset

Hi all so i have a sample of data from Spain
and i have this (sample) dataframe

```
>mydf
   brand             model    Year_of_first_registration     Fuel_type
  1 OPEL           ZAFIRA              2012                 DiÃ©sel
  2 TOYOTA         YARIS               2006                 Gasolina
  3 CITROEN        XSARA               2005                 DiÃ©sel
  4 HONDA          SH125               2010                 Gasolina
  5 TOYOTA         PRIUS               2011                 Gasolinaere
```

The thing is that when im trying to subset based on **year of registration** everything is going as plan

```
>yor<- subset(mydf, Year_of_first_registration=="2012")

> brand    model      Year_of_first_registration     Fuel_type
 1 OPEL   ZAFIRA                 2012                DiÃ©sel
```

but when im trying to subset based on model or brand im getting a dataframe with zero observations while it should at least one.

```
sd<- subset(mydf, model=="ZAFIRA")

sd
[1] brand                      model                      Year_of_first_registration Fuel_type                 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

My only exception at models was with YARIS

I tried to change my keyboard language to spanish just in case they are in spanish but didnt have any result

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(mydf)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When running the following code it should work:

```
# subset based on model or brand
subset(mydf, model == "ZAFIRA")
```

Output:

```
  brand  model Year_of_first_registration Fuel_type
1  OPEL ZAFIRA                       2012   DiÃ©sel
```

A different option is using `filter` from the `dplyr` package. You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr) 
mydf %>%
  filter(model == "ZAFIRA")
```

Output:

```
  brand  model Year_of_first_registration Fuel_type
1  OPEL ZAFIRA                       2012   DiÃ©sel
```

## Your data

```
mydf <- structure(list(brand = c("OPEL", "TOYOTA", "CITROEN", "HONDA", 
                                  "TOYOTA"), model = c("ZAFIRA", "YARIS", 
                                                                                 "XSARA", "SH125", "PRIUS"), Year_of_first_registration = c(2012L, 
                                                                                                                                                                         2006L, 2005L, 2010L, 2011L), Fuel_type = c("DiÃ©sel", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "Gasolina", "DiÃ©sel", "Gasolina", "Gasolinaere")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -5L))
```

Comment: I just tried it and i got again the zero rows(i tried both filter)

Comment: @savvaspehlivanidis, try using the data i provided above.

Comment: yeah with your data works but i dont understant why with my data does not

Comment: @savvaspehlivanidis, I think it is because when looking at your data, it seems that the data is not aligned well. When looking at the headers, you see that some headers need backspaces. You should align the columns right.

Comment: the structure is like `mydf <- structure(list(brand = c("OPEL", "TOYOTA", "CITROEN", "HONDA", "TOYOTA"), model = c("ZAFIRA", "YARIS", "XSARA", "SH125", "PRIUS"), Year_of_first_registration = c(2012L, 2006L, 2005L, 2010L, 2011L), Fuel_type = c("DiÃ©sel", "Gasolina", "DiÃ©sel", "Gasolina", "Gasolinaere")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -5L))`

Comment: @savvaspehlivanidis, could you please share your `str(mydf)`?

Comment: `> str(mydf)
'data.frame': 5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ brand                     : chr  "OPEL                          " "TOYOTA                        " "CITROEN                       " "HONDA                         " ...
 $ model                     : chr  "ZAFIRA                        " "YARIS" "XSARA                         " "SH125                         " ...
 $ Year_of_first_registration: chr  "2012" "2006" "2005" "2010" ...
 $ Fuel_type                 : chr  "DiÃ©sel" "Gasolina" "DiÃ©sel" "Gasolina" ...`

Comment: @savvaspehlivanidis Looks like you have a lot of whitespace in your data.frame. Such that `"ZAFIRA      "` with white spaces at the end is not the same or equal to `"ZAFIRA"` without the whitespace. You can try `trimws(model)` to see if that will help.

Comment: I just corrected it thanks for the assistance @Ben